# Select by composite foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

May I know is there any difference on using AND or EXIST for selecting on 2 tables by composite foreign key?

AND example:

```
SELECT comp1, comp2 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE comp1 = ( SELECT comp1 FROM TABLE2 ) 
  AND comp2 = ( SELECT comp2 FROM TABLE2 );
```

EXISTS example:

```
SELECT comp1, comp2 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * 
              FROM TABLE2 
              WHERE TABLE1.comp1 = TABLE2.comp1 
                and TABLE1.comp2 = TABLE2.comp2);
```

Thanks.

Comment: hi, according to jim, first one may return error, so if i change it to a single sub select, will it still have the same flaw?

Comment: Jim is right. if you use `=` you will most probably get an error (which is not the case when using an `IN` condition).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is not correct even if the `=` is changed to an `IN` operator, because you are comparing individual values instead of the combination of the values.

The make the first one correct you would need to re-write it as:

```
select comp1, comp2 
from table1
where (comp1, comp2) IN (select comp1, comp2 from table2);
```

Consider the following example:

```
insert into table1 (comp1, comp2) values (1,2);
insert into table1 (comp1, comp2) values (2,1);
insert into table1 (comp1, comp2) values (1,1);
insert into table1 (comp1, comp2) values (2,2);

insert into table2 (comp1, comp2) values (1,1);
insert into table2 (comp1, comp2) values (2,2);
```

Your first statement (when using `IN` instead of `=`) will return all rows from table1 which is clearly not correct. If you are comparing the combination of the two values then my statement correctly returns only two rows from table1.

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3c7a/1

Comment: hi thanks for the explanation, i understand the 'not the in same row'

Answer (score 1):

In the 1st case you'll get error if any of:

```
SELECT comp1 FROM TABLE2
SELECT comp2 FROM TABLE2
```

would give you more than 1 value; probably it will.

EXISTS is true when resultset rows count is more than 0, so the 2nd looks correct.

Comment: will `SELECT comp1, comp2 FROM TABLE1 WHERE comp1 IN ( SELECT comp1 FROM TABLE2 ) AND comp2 IN ( SELECT comp2 FROM TABLE2 );` works?

Comment: I see "=" but not "IN" in your initial message

Comment: @curiosity it won't give error but results will probably be not what author wants

Comment: @curiosity if you want get only records from Table1 that have corresponding rows (by composite key) from Table2 then your #2 is correct

Comment: So only the exists example is workable even if '=' is changed to 'IN'?

Comment: @curiosity: if you use `IN` instead of `=` the first one will work as well - but see my comment: you can do that with only a *single* sub-select.

Comment: @curiosity you also may use T1 INNER JOIN T2 oON composite key and select T1's fields, but SQL plan made by optimizer might be same

Comment: a JOIN does not necessarily return the same result as an `IN` or `EXISTS` query.

Comment: but according to jim, he said "it won't give error but results will probably be not what author wants"

Comment: INNER JOIN will result the same as EXISTS in #2 case

Comment: differense between 1st case with "IN" and 2nd case with EXISTS is the following: if you have rows in T2 like [1, 2], [3,4] and a row in T1 like [1,4] then 1st will result 1 record whereas 2nd will result an empty set

Comment: oh, i think get it now, will horse example `where (comp1, comp2) in ( select comp1, comp2 from table2)` work correctly? because it will not have the 'not in same row' flaw.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if comp1 and com2 are not PK or unique in T2 then  INNER JOIN can result more records than EXISTS. But i understood thay are PK...

Comment: that's what I was aiming at. In this case it's OK, but in general a JOIN and an IN condition are not equivalent.

Comment: @curiosity if comp1 and comp2 are unique per T1 or T2 then your IN from above will give same results as EXISTS. Why you dont like EXISTS? :) explain plan will probably be the same...

Comment: @jim, haha because it looks cleaner than exists, comp1,comp2 is pkey for any one of the tables